# To display each exported record in each cell in table in word file

Tags: c#, sql, button, gridview

I have exported data from gridview to word same as in the gridview .

But i need to show that each record in different cell in table in word while exporting

M using windows application  in dot net

I got output while exporting data from gridview 
-----Bill Detail-----

ID      Name        Location
1       rasdf           sdf
2       sdf         jlkj
3       dfdf            dfdf
4       dsaf            sdfdsfds
5       king            mumbai

This is like table with 4 colums..... I need output like this

1  rasdf  sdf       2  sdf  jlkj        3   dfdf  dfdf      4   dsaf sdfdsfds
5  king  mumbai

**This code written in export button**

```
private void Eportto work(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            sfd.Filter = "Excel Documents (*.doc)|*.doc";

            if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
             {
              ExportToWord(); 
                } 
        }


private void ExportToWord()
        {

            string strForPrint = "";


                string strHeaderTitle = "";

                for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    strHeaderTitle = strHeaderTitle.ToString() + Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Columns[j].HeaderText) + "\t\t";
                }

                strForPrint += strHeaderTitle + "\r\n";

                // writing datagridview data.

                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i++)
                {
                    string strLineData = "";

                    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells.Count; j++)
                    {

                        strLineData = strLineData.ToString() + Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value);
                        if (j == 1)
                        {
                            strLineData = strLineData + "\t\t\t";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            strLineData = strLineData + "\t\t";
                        }
                    }

                    strForPrint += strLineData + "\r\n";
                }


            Encoding utf16 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1254);


            byte[] output = utf16.GetBytes(strForPrint);

            FileStream fs = new FileStream(sfd.FileName, FileMode.Create);

            BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);

          bw.Write(output, 0, output.Length); //write data into file
          MessageBox.Show("File Created.....");

            bw.Flush();

            bw.Close();

            fs.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try to implement with this example:**

In order to insert data into word table from C# windows application you can refer the link shared below:

[msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa537149%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

change strForPrint += strLineData + "\r\n"; inside for loop of --> for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i++)

to

```
 If(strForPrint%4==0)//4 rows has been added
 {
   strForPrint += strLineData + "\r\n"; //go to new line
 }
 else {
  strLineData = strLineData + "\t\t"; //4 rows not added stay on same line
 }
```

Hope this logic is clear

Comment: 1 rasdf sdf        2 sdf jlkj           3 dfdf dfdf   4 dsaf sdfdsfds
5 king mumbai

Comment: I need a table in word that store each record in one cell....table contains 4 columns and N no of rows as we have no of records . if suppose i have 6 records . In first row 4 records will be stored and remaining 2 to display on 2 nd row that occupy first two cells in that row